# Existence of Subspace such that restriction map is injective

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces and $f: V \to W$ is a onto linear map. Then how does one show that there exists a subspace $S \neq \{0\}$ of $V$ such that $f$ restricted to $S$ is one-one

Comment: Can't you just let $S=\{0\}$? then $f |_S$ is trivially one-to-one. Or do you have any more premises?

Comment: @OveAhlman : Oh thats the trivial one. Assume $S \neq \{0\}$

Comment: ... we also need to assume $W\neq \{0\}$ then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need not assume finite dimensionality (as long as we trust the Axiom of Choice far enough to guarantee that every vector space has a basis).

Pick a basis of $\{w_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $W$. For each $i\in I$, there exists $v_i\in V$ with $f(v_i)=w_i$. Then the space $S$ spanned by all $v_i$, $i\in I$ does what we want: If $f(\sum c_iv_i)=0$ then $\sum c_iw_i=0$, hence all $c_i=0$.

All we need in order to have $S\ne0$ is that $W\ne 0$, of course.

---

Actually, upon rereading the exact problem statement: The *exact* claim holds even in the absence of the Axiom of Choice (because it only requires one-to-one, not bijective). Pick $w\in W\setminus \{0\}$, pick $v\in V$ with $f(v)=w$. Let $S$ be the span of $v$.

Answer (score 0):

If $V,W$ are finite dimensional, choose a basis for $V$ sat $\{b_1,...,b_k\}$. Then $\{f(b_1),...,f(b_k)\}$ span $W$ (since $f$ is onto). Then think of how to chose the subspace $S$ of $V$ so that restricted to $S$, the function $f$ is one-one.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that $\{b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n\}$ spans $W$ and $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m\}$ spans $V$with $m>n$, we will have $f:V\to W$ being onto as it'll map the varying basis members of $V$ onto the basis of $W$. However we can just pick som set of the basis $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m\}$ such that $f$ becomes injective on these sets, then our $S$ is just the span of these basis.

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional...

Let $n=\dim(V)$, $m=\dim(W)$, $M$ be the matrix of $f$ with some basis.  Then $m\leq n$ and some $m\times m$ minor has non-zero determinant.  The $m$ columns correspond to $m$ basis elements of $V$, and restricting $f$ to the subspace of $V$ spanned by these basis vectors gives you an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

You lack the assumption that $W\ne\{0\}$. In this case just take $v\in V$ such that $f(v)\ne0$ and $S$ the span of $v$. Since $f(v)\ne0$, also $f(\alpha v)\ne0$ whenever $\alpha\ne0$.

---

If you want a subspace $S$ of $V$ such that the restriction of $f$ to $S$ is one-to-one *and onto*, then just take a complement of $\ker f$, that is, a subspace $S$ such that $S\cap\ker f=\{0\}$ and $S+\ker f=V$.

If $g\colon S\to W$ is the restriction of $f$, then
$$
\ker g=S\cap\ker f=\{0\}
$$
by assumption, so $g$ is one-to-one.

Let $w\in W$; then there is $v\in V$ such that $f(v)=w$. Since $S+\ker f=V$, we can write $v=x+y$ with $x\in S$ and $y\in\ker f$, so
$$
w=f(v)=f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)=g(x)
$$
and so $g$ is onto.

---

One can note that the extended statement (there is $S$ such that the restriction of $f$ to $S$ is one-to-one and onto) is equivalent to the statement that every subspace has a complement. For the converse, just consider the canonical projection $V\to V/U$, where $U$ is the subspace we want to find the complement of.