# Existence of a certain subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $ V $ and $ W $ be two finitely dimensional vector spaces and $ f:V \rightarrow W $ be a linear map. Does there exist a subspace $ U $ of $ V $ such that $$ Ker(f) \cap U=\{ 0 \} $$ and $$ Im(f)=\{ f(u)| u \in U \} $$?

Comment: First, please share your thoughts or effort. Second, do you know about the orthogonal complement of a vector subspace? See the following post and further posts: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1669258/show-that-there-is-a-subspace-u-of-v-such-that-v-cong-u-oplus-w?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You can find there:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1682705/existence-of-subspace-such-that-restriction-map-is-injective

Comment: @Test123 For the orthogonal complement, you would need an orthogonal form that satisfies $U \cap U^{\perp} = \{0\}$ for all spaces, you don't always have that.

Comment: @DirkLiebhold Note that it is finite dimensional so up to isomorphism it can be seen as $\mathbb{R}^N$ for some $N$.

Comment: @Test123 Of course, if you assume the base field to be $\mathbb{R}$... but how about vector spaces over a finite field, for example? You will run into quite some trouble to find such an orthogonal form there.

Comment: @DirkLiebhold This is not a place for a conversation but..Each comment or answer is adapted to the OP. It is not about showing off or being very strict e.g. by mentioning about finite fields, when the OP clearly has some more basic gaps/questions. My comment was suggesting that the OP should look into that direction, nothing more and nothing less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, such a subspace exists. One construction that gives us such a subspace is as follows:

Begin with a basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ of $\ker f$. This linearly independent subset can necessarily be extended to a basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_k,v_{k+1},\dots,v_n\}$ of $V$ (where $n = \dim V$).  Take $U$ to be the subspace spanned by the vectors $\{v_{k+1},\dots,v_n\}$.  I will leave it to you to prove that this $U$ has the desired properties.

A bit more concretely: if $V$ is an inner product space (or for that matter if $V$ comes with a suitable bilinear form, as mentioned in the comments), then it suffices to take $U = \ker f^{\perp}$.  In the case wherein $V = \Bbb R^n$ with the canonical inner product (i.e. dot-product), $\ker f ^\perp$ coincides with the "row-space" of the matrix associated with $f$.

Comment: Thank you! I should have figured it out on my own. This was not hard at all. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 2):

We know that $ker(f)$ is a subspace of $V$. Take the basis of the $ker(f)$, let it be $\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_k\}$. Extend this basis to a basis of $V$, say $\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_k,v_{k+1},\cdots,v_n\}$. Then let $U=\operatorname{span}\{v_{k+1},\cdots,v_n\}.$